# Getting a NumberFormatException in Talend

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, talend

I am getting a NumberFormatException in talend ETL tool for the following statement:

```
Integer.parseInt("+2");
```

Error details:

```
Exception in component tJavaRow_3
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+2"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
```

Which is really a simple code that runs without any issue in my test java program.

```
public class Main { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      String s = "+000000100"; 
      System.out.println(String.valueOf(new Integer(s))); 
   } 
}
```

Actually am getting this value from a positional file and the value can be something like +0002 or -0002 (Some valid number prefixed with sign). And one thing is sure there will not be any decimals in the input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context `+2` must mean a positive number `2`. Watch out when passing strings to the function that does the parsing, because since it parses ints some expressions such as `3.5` or `3,5` (decimals) will not result like expected. Double.parseDouble or Float.parseFloat should be used in those cases instead if you have control over that code. On the other hand, negative numbers like `-2` will be parsed withour any problem.

**EDIT:** If you're using positional files just remove the + from the beginning of your string either by using a regular expression or obtaining a substring. You can, also, use `startsWith("+")` to check if the string starts with +.

Answer (score 2):

`+2` is not a valid intefer. It should be just `2`.

Comment: Actually am getting this value from a positional file and the value can be something like +0002 or -0002 (Some valid number prefixed with sign). And this code works in my java test program.

`public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  String s = "+000000100";
  System.out.println(new Integer(s));
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(new Integer(s)));
  System.out.println(s);
 }
}`

Comment: Are you sure about +0002? I just tried it. It failed with NumberFormatException. Can you post your test code?

Answer (score 1):

Just zap the `+` from the start of the number:

```
num = num.replaceAll("\\+", "");
// parse, etc.
```